# In there a common name for the surface $z = x^y$?

Tags: surfaces

Is there a standard name for the surface $z=x^y$, the way we have 'plane' for $z=x+y$, and 'hyperbolic paraboloid' or 'saddle' for $z=x y$ (which is congruent to the surface $z=\frac{x^2 - y^2}{2}$), as examples?

Comment: Where did this surface come about? It's not defined when $x,y<0$ (for almost all $x,y$), and other than there it's fairly nasty.

Comment: No known name, no known properties, a poor apatrid function...